# Eliminate the epsilon-productions

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, context-free-language

I have trouble with these type of questions. Anyone can help me?

Eliminate the epsilon-productions in the following CFG.

S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 |€

X -> Z | 0

Y -> ZYU | €

Z -> 0Z1 | XZWZ | €

W -> X | Y | 01

Answer (score 2):

The rule is this: if X -> epsilon then you can add productions of the form Y -> rs wherever there is a production like Y -> rXs, and then eliminate X -> epsilon. The only exception is that the production S -> epsilon cannot be eliminated without removing the empty string from the generated language. If some nonterminals turn out to be equivalent, they should be condensed to a single symbol to avoid loops.

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 |€
X -> Z | 0
Y -> ZYU | €
Z -> 0Z1 | XZWZ | €
W -> X | Y | 01
```

We can start with Y:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | epsilon
X -> Z | 0
Y -> ZYU | ZU
Z -> 0Z1 | XZWZ | epsilon
W -> X | Y | 01 | epsilon
```

Let's to W next:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | epsilon
X -> Z | 0
Y -> ZYU | ZU
Z -> 0Z1 | XZWZ | XZZ | epsilon
W -> X | Y | 01
```

Let's do Z next:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | epsilon
X -> Z | 0 | epsilon
Y -> ZYU | ZU | YU | U
Z -> 0Z1 | XZWZ | XZZ | 01 | XWZ | XZW | XW | XZ | X
W -> X | Y | 01
```

We see productions X -> Z and Z -> X; so these symbols are equivalent. Combining:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | epsilon
X -> 0 | epsilon | 0X1 | 01 | XW | XX
Y -> XYU | XU | YU | U
W -> X | Y | 01
```

Now let's do X:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | 00 | epsilon
X -> 0 | 0X1 | 01 | W | XX
Y -> XYU | XU | YU | U
W -> X | Y | 01 | epsilon
```

We see productions X -> W and W -> X; so those symbols are equivalent. Combining:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | 00 | epsilon
X -> 0 | 0X1 | 01 | XX | Y | epsilon
Y -> XYU | XU | YU | U
```

We do X again:

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 11 | 00 | epsilon
X -> 0 | 0X1 | 01 | XX | Y
Y -> XYU | XU | YU | U
```

That should do it, unless one of the rules I used was wrong (equivalent symbols can be combined, the rule for eliminating epsilon), one of the simplifications I made was in error, or I made a wrong assumption (that U is a terminal since it's not on the LHS of a production).